# How to hide accounts/contacts from other members in same org but different project?

Tags: security

My client has two distinct project in one SF instance. Ideally, neither project should see each other's accounts and contacts.

What would be a good way when creating an account or contact to make sure that each user only sees account and contact in their project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Create groups for each project (project1, project2)
2. Set [OWD](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_sharing.htm&type=5) for Account/Contact as private
3. Add [sharing rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_sharing_rules_create_account.htm) for Account/Contact, based on record owner, so that if owner is from project1 group, then record is shared with project1 group.